# Horizontal axis Point charts on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table:

[image: Data sets]

I want to create this kind of chart :

[image: CHART]

i want dataset from each column put in  horizontal axis.

i tried to do that but i have next result , the dataset from each column draw in vertical axis :

[image: rong chart]]

i need them like this pic  :

[image: hand draw example ]]

THEN I HAVE THIS DIAGRAM PIC 5:
the badges drawed for Patient not for RB1 ... RB6

[image: hand draw example ]]

Comment: What is your specific question about doing that?  What's hanging you up?  What have you found in researching the task?  What have you attempted and in what ways were the results unsatisfactory?

Comment: i want dataset from each column put in horizontal axis !

Comment: Your result looks pretty similar except you don't have range bars on the columns (are those needed?  If so, what would determine them?), and you have suppressed the legend.  Can you be more explicit about what the problem is?

Comment: thank you for answer .
i need them like pic 4 , i make it with paint

Comment: Is the only issue that you want to label the X axis with the variable names?

Comment: If so, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-axis-labels-in-a-chart-1c32436b-fb12-450b-aefa-cc7e4584456a

Comment: I i have tryed this , but the badges drawed for Ptient not for RB1 ... RB6
i need that badges drawed for RBs

Answer (score 0):

Aha! You want a [scattergram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot).

https://yodalearning.com/tutorials/create-scatter-plots-excel/ offers a tutorial in how to do that.

- Select all the cells that contain data
- Click on Insert tab
- Look for Charts group in the Ribbon Bar
- Under Charts group, you will find Scatter (X, Y) Chart
- Choose style 9 to vary the shape of the objects, then
- Add a legend at the right, and
- Scale the Y-axis.